# API Limit increase in Developer ORg

Tags: api, limits

We have a developer org where we have API Org limit of 15000 but we need to increase the limit to 2,00,000.

Can this be increased with help of salesforce.com support.

Comment: Who do you think would be best suited to answer this?

Comment: Hi, I logged a case with Salesforce.com but wanted to know anyone managed to get increased with help of  SFDC support.

Comment: Hi Arun, How did you raised case with salesforce for developer org? I think this facility comes only when you have actual production org. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: HI, I logged a case  with salesforce.com support. They asked for the business reason for request in increase API Limit.